# Out of memory error while uploading file into a blob

Tags: windows-vista, postgresql

I received a out of memory error

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 53200
```

from postgres while trying to upload a 10MB file into a single row with a column of blob-type `bytea`.

- **Which configuration parameters should be changed to allow inserts of this size, or should this work out of the box without modifications?**
- *Is there an option like in informix-db to create so called blob-spaces?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the full error message? Not just the SQLState, but the actual message.

That said, normally, PostgreSQL doesn't impose a limit at that point. Your operating system might - check if you're running with some ulimit's for the process, for example.

I have no idea what a blob-space is in informix, but you want to look into "large objects" rather than inline blobs. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/largeobjects.html.

Comment: Thanks the most important to me was "PostgreSQL doesn't impose a limit "